# Financial report query

Tags: performance, sql, finance

I have been tasked with creating financial reports. I am looking for any suggestions on improving performance, readability/formatting  or best practices.

```
/*setting dummy parameters */
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
DECLARE @startProduct NVARCHAR = ''
DECLARE @endProduct NVARCHAR = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
DECLARE @startGroup NVARCHAR = ''
DECLARE @endGroup NVARCHAR = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
DECLARE @startDepartment NVARCHAR = ''
DECLARE @endDepartment NVARCHAR = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '01/05/2000'
DECLARE @endDate DATE = CAST('31/05/2012' AS DATE)
DECLARE @StartTime TIME  = '08:00:00'
DECLARE @endTime TIME = '17:00:00'
DECLARE @grouping INT = 0
DECLARE @site  INT = 21
/*
ProductCode = 0
ProductGroup = 1
Department = 2
Pump = 3
Date = 4
*/

SELECT
     CASE @grouping
        WHEN 0 THEN P.Code
        WHEN 1 THEN P.[Group]
        WHEN 2 THEN P.Department
        WHEN 3 THEN P.[Description]
        WHEN 4 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,RPS.SalesDateTime,103)
    END AS GroupCode,  
    CASE @grouping
        WHEN 0 THEN P.[Description]
        WHEN 1 THEN PG.[Description]
        WHEN 2 THEN PD.[Description]
        WHEN 3 THEN 'PUMP: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,RPS.PumpId) +' HOSE: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,RPS.HoseId)
        WHEN 4 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CAST(FLOOR(CAST(RPS.SalesDateTime AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
    END AS [GroupDescription],
    SUM(RPS.Quantity) AS Quantity,
    SUM( CASE
            WHEN P.GSTable = 1 THEN  RPS.TotalAmount / 1.1
            ELSE RPS.TotalAmount
         END) AS AmountX,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN P.GSTable = 1 THEN (rps.TotalAmount * .10)
            ELSE 0 END
        ) AS GST,
    SUM(RPS.UnitLastCost * RPS.Quantity) AS CostXgst,
    SUM(RPS.TotalAmount) AS AmountInc,
    FLOOR(ROUND(((1 -
        (
        SUM(RPS.UnitLastCost * RPS.Quantity)
            /
            NULLIF(SUM
            (
                CASE
                    WHEN P.GSTable = 1 THEN  RPS.TotalAmount / 1.1
                    ELSE RPS.TotalAmount
                END
            ),0))) * 100 ),0))

          AS Margin
FROM
    RetailPosSales RPS
        JOIN Products P ON RPS.ProductCode = P.Code
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductGroups PG ON P.[Group] = PG.Code /*need this if the grouping is 1*/
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductDepartments PD ON P.Department = PD.Code  /*need this if the grouping is 2 */
WHERE
    ((@grouping <> 3) OR (@grouping = 3 AND RPS.IsFuelSale = 1)) /*When grouping by pump, only allow fuel products */
    AND P.Code BETWEEN @startProduct AND @endProduct
    AND P.[Group] BETWEEN @startGroup AND @endGroup
    AND P.Department BETWEEN @startDepartment AND @endDepartment
    AND CAST(RPS.SalesDateTime AS DATE) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND CAST(RPS.SalesDateTime AS TIME) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @endTime
    AND RPS.SiteId = @site
GROUP BY
    CASE @grouping
        WHEN 0 THEN P.Code
        WHEN 1 THEN P.[Group]
        WHEN 2 THEN P.Department
        WHEN 3 THEN P.[Description]
        WHEN 4 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,RPS.SalesDateTime,103)
    END,
    CASE @grouping
        WHEN 0 THEN P.[Description]
        WHEN 1 THEN PG.[Description]
        WHEN 2 THEN PD.[Description]
        WHEN 3 THEN 'PUMP: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,RPS.PumpId) +' HOSE: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,RPS.HoseId)
        WHEN 4 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CAST(FLOOR(CAST(RPS.SalesDateTime AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
    END
ORDER BY
    GroupCode,
    GroupDescription
```

Comment: Which database (SQL Server, Oracle, other?) and version?

Comment: Sorry. mssql2008+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using the same expressions for the `GroupCode` and `GroupDescription` columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.  That's asking for trouble later on if someone needs to modify either expression, especially given their size.  Instead, use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    GroupCode,
    GroupDescription,
    -- etc
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE /* etc */ END AS GroupCode,
            CASE /* etc */ END AS GroupDescription,
            -- etc
        FROM
            -- etc
        WHERE
            -- etc
    ) AS dummy
GROUP BY
    GroupCode,
    GroupDescription
ORDER BY
    GroupCode,
    GroupDescription
```

*EDIT:*

There may be some other opportunities to use subqueries to reduce duplication of expressions.  For example, the expression for the column `AmountX` is also used in the `Margin` calculation.